# Webpack error on Angular website

Tags: angular, webpack

I use Webpack for an Angular 2 website. When I build it and upload it on my server, I test it in different machines and it works without any error. However, in most of my client's computers, the page doesn't load at all and it has the following error on console:

```
polyfills.0538e73….bundle.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined at __webpack_require__ 
(polyfills.0538e73….bundle.js:1) at Object.<anonymous> 
(main.c4452dc….bundle.js:1) at __webpack_require__ 
(polyfills.0538e73….bundle.js:1) at Object.<anonymous> 
(main.c4452dc….bundle.js:1) at __webpack_require__ 
(polyfills.0538e73….bundle.js:1) at Object.<anonymous> 
(main.c4452dc….bundle.js:1) at __webpack_require__ 
(polyfills.0538e73….bundle.js:1) at Object.<anonymous> 
(main.c4452dc….bundle.js:1) at __webpack_require__ 
(polyfills.0538e73….bundle.js:1) at Object.<anonymous> 
(main.c4452dc….bundle.js:1) at __webpack_require__ 
(polyfills.0538e73….bundle.js:1) at Object.<anonymous> 
(main.c4452dc….bundle.js:1) at __webpack_require__ 
(polyfills.0538e73….bundle.js:1) at Object.<anonymous> 
(main.c4452dc….bundle.js:1) at __webpack_require__ 
(polyfills.0538e73….bundle.js:1)
```

Since I don't have experience on Webpack, I don't know what other files/code do you need to identify the error. I spent 2 days on Google to find something similar, but in most of the cases, the authors could reproduce the error. I cannot reproduce it on any of my machine. But I have verified it on my client's machines.

**Those are from my local, dev machine:**

node --version: v7.5.0

npm --version: 4.1.2

**Those on my production server:**

node --version: v6.10.3

npm --version: 3.10.10

and the `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
    },
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es6"
    ],
    "types": [
      "hammerjs",
      "node",
      "source-map",
      "uglify-js",
      "webpack"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ],
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "forkChecker": true,
    "useWebpackText": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "atom": { "rewriteTsconfig": false }
}
```

the `webpack.config.ts`

```
// Look in ./config folder for webpack.dev.js
switch (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
  case 'prod':
  case 'production':
    module.exports = require('./config/webpack.prod')({env: 'production'});
    break;
  case 'dev':
  case 'development':
  default:
    module.exports = require('./config/webpack.dev')({env: 'development'});
}
```

Here is the [webpack.dev](https://gist.github.com/ventouris/c381a5d9a2cf67e230ecd176bd93f9ed) and here the [webpack.prod](https://gist.github.com/ventouris/61a1c7df4b2fe7fc9f70cd044544f20e)

The order of scripts on my `index.html`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.0538e73c900216f4d2d0.bundle.js" defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.e1aa59d8e719a224eb3a.bundle.js" defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.c4452dc09fbc13bd7362.bundle.js" defer></script>
```

Comment: To identify the error, it's better to add: your webpack configuration, `node --version` and `npm --version` on your production server. Also, the `tsconfig.json` file can be great to have to identify your target (es5, es6, etc).

Comment: Thanks for giving hints and not down voting :) I have included from my dev machine and I will check them asap on the production server.

Comment: https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/issues/456 this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is most likely triggered by the loading order of the scripts. Assuming you have three chunks of scripts named *polyfill*, *vendor* and *main*, please check in the built `index.html` that the scripts are loaded in the following order:

- polyfills
- vendor
- main

To solve this, look at the configuration of HtmlWebpackPlugin, typically in `config/webpack.common.js` if your project is based on *angular2-webpack-starter*. It's something like this:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: 'src/index.html',
  title: METADATA.title,
  chunksSortMode: 'dependency',   // <-- this is important
  metadata: METADATA,
  inject: 'head'
})
```